# Проблема "требуется идентификатор" элемента max()

Tags: c++, namespace, препроцессор

Столкнулся с проблемой перекрывания друг друга одноимёнными программными элементами (если это так можно назвать). То есть, используя max вместе с библиотекой windows.h, в которой содержится директива:

```
#define max(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

В данном коде возникает ошибка "требуется идентификатор" на элементах max:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

short safeInput() {

short val = 0;

while (!(std::cin >> val)) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Wrong input, only integers are expected!" << std::endl;
}

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

return val;
```

}

p.s Если не подключать библиотеку windows.h, то всё нормально.

**Как решить её и вообще в будущем разграничивать подобные одноимённые элементы, предотвращать подобные ошибки, если пространство имён не помогает (ну или помогает, однако я пока что не знаю как)?**

Comment: `#undef max`. Это одна из проблем макросов - у них нет ограничивающей области видимости.

Comment: А ещё лучше использовать NOMINMAX - и не будет с ними проблем.

Comment: @KoVadim: Что это такое и как использовать?

Comment: #define NOMINMAX перед подключением виндового ашника

Comment: @acade: Спасибо! Помогло. Где лучше использовать эту директиву: в самом начале кода где подключаются различные хэдэры и библиотеки или непосредственно в тех участках кода, где нужно это проблему убрать?

Comment: @Steindvart, эту директиву нужно использывать после включения заголовка, в котором определен макрос `max` (в вашем случае `#include <windows.h>`). Рассмотрите также вариант с определением макроса `NOMINMAX`

Comment: @acad, да, рассмотрел. Спасибо большое, ребята!

Comment: Ещё один способ борьбы с windows.h и подобными - обернуть нужную вам функциональность в класс/набор функций со своим заголовочным и исходным файлом, и подключать windows.h  только в этом исходном файле. Тогда пользователи этого интерфейса просто не увидят содержимое windows.h. Хотя #undef иногда всеже приходится использовать, уже при реализации этого интерфейса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используется хак - заключение в скобки. Например, закрывающая скобка (да и любой символ, не эквивалентный пробелу) после имени макроса перед скобками с параметрами `(std::max)(a,b)` не даёт расширять макросы с параметрами.

Ваш пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

short safeInput() {

short val = 0;

while (!(std::cin >> val)) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Wrong input, only integers are expected!" << std::endl;
}

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(), '\n');

return val;
```

Не забудьте, что ещё и `abs` часто определяют макросами.

Answer (score 2):

Либо сразу после включения `windows.h` сделайте

```
#undef min
#undef max
```

Либо еще до включения `windows.h` определите макро `NOMINMAX` (лучше - глобально в настройках проекта).